# proper way to set an async data fetch timeout in react using useEffect / useState only after prior fetch has succeeded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, react-hooks, use-effect

I'm currently fetching data in react successfully from an API with async / await, and a timeout after each successful fetch to re-fetch data. However, I'm getting a warning:

`Line 14:6:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'getData'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps`

This is my current code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import * as CONSTANTS from '../../constants/myConstants';

function MyPage() {

  const [myData, setMyData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchDataTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
      getData();
    }, CONSTANTS.UPDATE_TIME);
    return () => clearTimeout(fetchDataTimeout);
  }, [myData]);

  async function getDataAsync() {
    console.log('get data async');
    try {
      const response = await fetch(CONSTANTS.PROXY_URL + CONSTANTS.API_URL, {
        headers: {
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': `Token ${CONSTANTS.API_TOKEN}`,
        }
      });
      console.log(response);
      return response;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }

  function getData() {
    console.log('get data');
    getDataAsync().then((response) => {
      console.log(response.status); //success?
      if (response.status === CONSTANTS.TOO_MANY_REQUESTS_CODE) {
        handleTooManyRequests();
      } else {
        response.json().then(data => {
          console.log('data:',data);
          if (data.data) {
            handleDataSuccess(data.data);
          } else {
            handleOtherError();
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }

  function handleDataSuccess(data) {
    setMyData(data);
    console.log(myData);
  }

  function handleOtherError(){
    console.error('other error');
  }

  function handleTooManyRequests(){
    console.error('too many requests');

  }

  return (
    <div>
      My Page
    </div>
  );
}

export default MyPage;
```

I know I can resolve this error if I move the `getData` function inside the useEffect hook. But then it will complain about that functions call (`handleDataSuccess()`).

How do I structure this with useEffect and useState so that I can fetch new data when a set amount of time has passed, but only after the existing `myData` has changed?

Comment: Aside from moving the functions inside useEffect, you can 1) add getData to the dependency list (and wrap in useCallback) or 2) move the functions outside MyPage but within it's scope.

Comment: Hi @eric99 - if you provide this comment as an answer / example I'm happy to accept.